# MySql dynamic column name

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

[major edit to make things clear]

I want to write a query that returns a dynamic column name like this:

`SELECT
        f2 AS 
    (
        SELECT column_name
        FROM column_names_tbl
        WHERE column_name = "experience"
                limit 0,1
    )
    FROM some_table`

so that would output the same as this:

    `SELECT
        f2 AS experience
    FROM some_table`

Answer (score 0):

This is no correct SQL syntax, even because the two queries (the selected field and it's alias) are both subqueries and unrelated to each other. So, there's also no possibility for mysql to distinguish what name you want to connect to what value, even if the syntax was correct...

You already use a more or less normalized relational table, so I suggest the following solution:

- you select the revision ID and name in a separate query; store them in PHP and use them for whatever you want
- next, you evaluate the following query into a separated result set: `SELECT ps.keyname, psv.keyvalue FROM page_setting_values AS psv INNER JOIN page_settings AS ps ON ps.id = psv.setting_id WHERE psv.page_revision_id = :revision` with :revision representing your revision id
- you may now assemble an associated array from that result set:

  `$settings = [];
   $result = $db->executeQuery('...')->fetchAll();
   foreach($result as $setting)
   {
       $settings[$setting['keyname']] = $setting['keyvalue'];
   }`

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, I will edit my question with no code to make it as simple as possible.